# Criteria building nhibernate

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, search, criteria

I was wondering if someone could help with an example criteria for nhibernate. I think I've got my head around fairly basic things, like finding records in a given table who's field matches a certain value etc. Where I'm currently tripping up is where you have a table with a foreign key for another table, and attempting to find rows from the first table based on some field in the second table.

As an example...

If I have

```
tblUser
pk int    ID
   int    CompanyID
   string Name
```

and

```
tblCompany
pk int     ID
   string CompanyName
```

How would I build criteria to retrieve all users that belong to a company with a certain name? I think I understand how to build appropriate mapping files/objects, I just can't figure out how to make the criteria look against subproperties of the initial object.

Any examples woudl be awesome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Criterias can't look at sub-properties directly, so if you want to access a sub-property you need to use an alias

```
session.CreateCriteria<User>()
    .CreateAlias("Company", "c") //the first argument is the property name from User
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("c.Name", companyName))
    .List<User>();
```

Also, the same restriction on nested properties exists for aliases, so if you had User -> Company -> Owner you would need two aliases

```
.CreateAlias("Company", "c")
.CreateAlias("c.Owner", "o")
```

Also, if you prefer to use aliases for the whole query you can give the root entity an alias as well when creating the criteria.

```
session.CreateCriteria<User>("u")
    .CreateAlias("u.Company", "c")
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("c.Name", companyName))
    .List<User>();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, KeeperOfTheSoul! You saved me some time. It's a good thing you're not here with me because I'd probably high five you so hard your arms would snap at the forearms and boy that would be a mess to clean up. Again, thanks for the help!